# Importing data into Address entity in CRM 13 failing

Tags: entity-framework, csv

I have some Account info that contains multiple addresses that I need to enter into CRM 13 for a client.  I was instructed by my PM to create a separate csv doc with the duplicate accounts and their info on them and import them into the Address entity, and that this should tie those records to their respective account records.  The problem I am having, though, is that every time I have tried to do the import, the process fails.  When I look at the log, I have two references that the data failed an import because of a parent id issue.  I get both this error: **The parent is not valid**; and this one under the last column on the log: **parent id not set for address type 1701**.

I have no idea what parent id I am supposed to map to, because there aren't any to map to when on the import field mapping set up.  I have tried creating a lookup field on the Address entity that calls back to the Account form, but that is not allowed by the system.  I have relabeled ALL the fields I have to map on the CSV doc to match the proper entity names, and it fails.  I have even tried to map it to the one primary key field name on the drop down, and it fails.  When I look at the fields individually, there is only one lookup field that goes back to the Account data: The Parent field.  It's the ONLY one I can think I could use, but when you go into the form editor it doesn't exist. This seems to be the only way I can do this like my PM wanted.

I am at a loss.  I have scoured the internet, and I can't find an answer to how to resolve this.  If anyone knows how I can import this data so that it ties to the Account entity, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that CRM 15 has some issues with showing fields in Firefox, at the moment, but not with IE.  And it was the last thing I thought to look at, until a coworker brought it up.  Problem solved.